# gnome-extensions not working on Ubuntu:20.04

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I installed on my new PC Ubuntu:20.04 gnome-extensions and it worked fine until one day it suddenly decided to stop working. I'm using gnome-shell:3.36.4, i do not know what to do or if i can do somethings. I tried to restart, reinstall the service,delete all extensions, also tweaks and firefox extension but these not working for me, so can someone help me?